# How to set default value of string column in Beego

Tags: go, orm, beego

I am trying to set a default column value for a string column in beego struct.

I tried the following:

```
string `orm:"column(method_type);default(test)"`
```

And some different versions of this but instead of inserting the default value supplied, the orm keeps sending blank string to table.

Used this as reference:
https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/models.md#default

Comment: what happens when you use quotes, e.g. `string \`orm:"column(method_type);default('test')"\``? not sure about it though

Comment: @xarantolus That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string `orm:"column:method_type;default:'test'"`
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: It's a part of beego's documents basically

Comment: @pppery’s point was to encourage you to edit your existing answer to provide further explanation to help people with a similar problem understand _why_ this works, not just _what_ to do. Could you do that? It would make this a more useful answer.